# Как обьединить рисунок и кнопки окне в Java

Tags: java

Учусь по одной из книг, по отдельности размещать кнопки и рисунки получается, а вот как их объединить - не могу понять, нет примитивного примера как это сделать. Вот код из книги для вывода рисунка в виде текста, а когда вставляю туда кнопку, то рисунок исчезает:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class GraphicsG extends Frame
{
        GraphicsG(String s)
        {
           super(s);
        }


        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC|Font.BOLD, 30));
            g.drawString("Hello, XXI Century World!", 20, 100);
        }



        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Button b = new Button("OK");
            Panel p = new Panel();
            Frame f = new GraphicsG("Здравствуй, мир XXI века!");
            p.add(b);
            f.add(p);
            f.setSize(400, 150);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
               public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev){
                  System.exit(0);
               }
            });
        }
     }
```

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, что вы хотите в итоге получить. Опиши поподробнее, может даже какие-то рисунки привести для наглядности.

Comment: @Vartlok, если закомментировать строки с кнопкой и панелью и их добавление на фрейм, то появится надпись `"Hello, XXI Century World!`. При добавлении кнопки на фрейм надпись пропадает, ТС же хочет и то, и то на одном фрейме.

Answer (score 1):

У вас происходит перекрытие, чтобы этого не было - воспользуйтесь Layout. [Вот тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html), например, туториал насчет этого с Oracle.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
}

public Test() {
    super("Здравствуй, мир XXI века!");       
    JButton button = new JButton("OK");             
    setSize(400, 150);    
    add(button);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    button.setLayout(null);
    button.setLocation(100,100);
    button.setSize(100,40);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC|Font.BOLD, 30));
    g.drawString("Hello, XXI Century World!", 20, 100);
}
```

Источник примера: [**enSO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136942/paint-in-jframe-not-working-java).

Comment: Да, теперь все норм, когда применил стиль отображения setLayout